# Android time tracking and limiting with local logging (not sending to a third party)?

Tags: android, time-management, parental-control

I only found [Kaspersky](https://my.kaspersky.com) which has the following problems for my purposes, in reverse order of importance:

1. It costs money to get detailed reports.
2. It's proprietary software rather than open source.
3. It sends all the activity information to their servers rather than logging it locally.

What I want is an Android app with the following features:

MUST:

1. Allow time limits to be set per application per day (preferably different for each day of the week if desired);
2. Allow time limits to be extended by some amount (e.g. in 15 minute increments) by entering a password;
3. Actually *prevent* the app from being used after the deadline, unless the right password is entered (it's okay if a *very* tech savvy user could circumvent the restriction, but ideally it should be impossible);
4. Log information *locally* as to what apps have been used for how long, with this information protected by a password (or at least prevent the logs from being purged without the password).

DESIRABLE:

1. Open source;
2. Costs no money.

If an app exists that can handle the time restrictions but *not* the tracking logs, that would be nice too, so long as it doesn't actually track the information and send it to some remote server like Kaspersky does.

Comment: @unor thanks for the edit, but it *is* absolutely required that the software not phone home; is there a tag for that?

Comment: No, we don’t have a tag for this. The [tag:offline] tag can be used for software that would typically require Internet access, but this doesn’t mean that the software isn’t allowed to use Internet if available. -- I would suggest to add it explicitly in the "MUST" list.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Qustodio](https://www.qustodio.com/en/) for my family. I have it installed on both Windows and Android devices.

It satisfies essential criteria 1/2/3. It does not satisfy #4, but I'm doubtful you will find something that allows this. It is a very niche requirement, IMHO - one of the features of these apps are the centralised management consoles.

Also, it is not free or open source; actually, there is a free version but it may not support #1 (not 100% sure).

Comment: According to their website, only the premium plans allow time limits to be set.  Re #4, the absolute requirement is that it NOT send usage information somewhere I don’t control.  If it doesn’t record it at all, fine.  Local logging is preferable but absence of remote logging is required.